# How to fetch milliseconds using date time?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a client who wants the execution time of a report to be shown on the base of their report. To accommodate them I've created a variable on the report (under report properties) called 'GroupExecutionTime' with the following expression:

```
=System.DateTime.Now
```

Then in the footer of the report I have the following:

```
="Execution Time: " +
IIf(Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).TotalSeconds < 1, "0 seconds", 
(
IIf(Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Hours > 0, Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Hours & " hour(s), ", "") +
IIf(Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Minutes > 0, Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Minutes & " minute(s), ", "") +
IIf(Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Seconds > 0, Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Seconds & " second(s)", ""))
)
```

Unfortunately the client has come back saying that they want me to show the milliseconds that the report has executed in when it's less then one second. It's a low priority requirement but curiosity and wish to satisfy the requirement have left me wondering how this is done? Unfortunately `System.DateTime.Now` doesn't appear to store anything below seconds.

**Fixed with the following (thanks to Anthony Sottile's answer)**

```
="Execution Time: " +
IIf(Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).TotalSeconds < 1, "0." & Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Milliseconds & " seconds.", 
(
IIf(Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Hours > 0, Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Hours & " hour(s), ", "") +
IIf(Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Minutes > 0, Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Minutes & " minute(s), ", "") +
IIf(Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Seconds > 0, Variables!GroupExecutionTime.Value.Subtract(Globals!ExecutionTime).Seconds & " second(s)", ""))
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resulting `TimeSpan` object from the `.Subtract()` method should have a `.Milliseconds` property that you can print.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.milliseconds%28v=vs.90%29

I'm not sure why DateTime.Now wouldn't record ms? If it doesn't, then this won't be of much assistance.  I unfortunately can't seem to spin up my instance of SSRS to test this myself...

Comment: I'm certain I tried this in my attempts in some form or another... I'm ducking out for lunch shortly but I'll take a crack at this one I return.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! I must have spelt it wrong the first time. Appreciated!